# Connecting Azure Synapse from Azure Databricks using User Assigned Managed Identity

Tags: pyspark, jdbc, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

Unable to connect to Azure Synapse from Azure Databricks - Notebook (PySpark) using JDBC, Using teh following JDBC url, getting exception:

jdbc:sqlserver://.sql.azuresynapse.net;database=;User Id=Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI;Use Encryption for Data=true;

Exception:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No JDBC credentials provided. You must specify JDBC credentials in either the URL or as user/password options, use Credential Passthrough, or set Service Principal Oauth2.0 authentication.

Code:

```
df.write \
      .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
      .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<synapse server name>.sql.azuresynapse.net;database=<dedicated pool name>;User Id=<UserAssignedManageIdentity>Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI;Use Encryption for Data=true; 
") \
      .option("useAzureMSI","true") \
      .option("dbtable", "table_name") \
      .option("truncate","false") \
      .option("tempDir", "abfss://<azure_storage_name>@<container_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/tempDir") \
      .mode("overwrite") \
      .save()
```

What is the correct connection string to connect to Synapse using User Managed Service Identity.

Background:

- User Managed Service Identity (umsi_synapse_user) been created
- Assigned Contributor role to User Managed Service Identity to access Synapse
- Created External user with User Managed Service Identity (umsi_synapse_user)
- Assigned 'db_owner' role to umsi_synapse_user

Comment: try 'jdbc:sqlserver://sqlsrv_name.azuresynaspe.windows.net:1433;database=sqldw_name;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.azuresynaspe.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;'
You using  the Azure Databricks Synapse Connector way of doing it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/synapse-analytics
https://mrjonlunn.com/2023/05/26/azure-databricks-synapse-connector/

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for managed identity on Azure Databricks clusters (yet). So you need to use other authentication methods.